# posting dynamically to S3

Tags: php, jquery, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

Good afternoon!
I am trying to replace my host with an S3 Amazon service for images. The website currently uploads images successfully using an uploader without problems. So the questions I have are about migrating from host to S3. Trust me I have read the Amazon support blogs and searched the net. But I can find no single, concise, or easy to understand technical advice--just a lot of Amazon jargon.

For info, at the moment the uploader does the two things you would expect it to do well:

1) it uploads the files to a target folder to the specified (Define) UPLOAD path(no problem)
2) it generates the image POSTS ready for processing (no problem).

It is a nice uploader with lots of goodies for image management so I don't want to replace it- I simply want to build a bridge from the outputs it creates (as above) into Amazon S3?.

So my specific questions are can anyone tell in simple terms how to:-

1. ..enable users to Upload the images posted by my uploader to Amazon S3
2. ..Allow users to get images back via their own dynamic page views.

Many thanks in anticipation

ps for info this is the uploader but im not sure that is needed bearing in mind it works as expected and produced the outputs above and I cannot replace it at this stage of the development process.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Comment: Looking at the wiki for the upload tool you are using, there are some S3 integration examples listed: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

Have you looked at those?

Comment: Thanks and yes. They do assume a pretty good understanding of the Amazon environment which I don't have have.  I was hopeful that someone on here had done this and could give an overview of the process/method not just the code.